# disallow selectors on nil object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

How do I temporarily disallow selectors to be called on nil objects.

Actually I was getting a Bad access exception, hours after I learned that some where I was using array with out calling alloc-init on it.

So can I have something like 
`#define DISABLE_SELECTORS_ON_NIL_OBJECTS` in prefix.h file
or some checkbox some where in project settings, or some exception which can disable selectors on nil objects, or
do I have to always put the code in  if(object != nil) ?

Comment: Fix your uninitialized array instead.

Comment: @Kreiri: I am expecting an answer to the question, not a fix to my example

Comment: How would you disable a call?! To disable a call don't write it. You write code that sends messages to objects (call). You have to ensure that your object exists yourself!

Comment: The whole "nil means nothing" thing is built into some pretty tight ASM in objc_msgSend.  I suppose you could patch and rebuild the runtime yourself but it seems easier to just initialize your variables.  Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad access exception means that your uninitialized object variable was *not* `nil`. In Objective-C, only instance variables are zeroed out for you automatically. Others hold whatever value is left in that memory location or register from the last time it was used. The only fix is to make sure the variable is initialized before you use it, even if that means setting it to `nil`.

Run the static analyzer on your code. It can often find issues like this and help you fix them.

Comment: So let say there were a `NSString` occupying that location before with value "NSString was here", then the initialized array will _hold_ that value? Thanks.

Comment: Rather, if an `NSArray *` occupies the same location that an `NSString *` did, the former will contain the same address the latter pointed to, until it is assigned to. Object variables are all pointers in Obj-C.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths So, it is the _address_ rather than the _value_ it previous held as claimed here?

Comment: @Unheilig: The value of a pointer *is* the address it contains, so the wording in this answer is accurate. If you're talking about whether things "are zeroed out for you automatically", that only matters when you're talking about the pointer, not about the pointed-to thing.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths All clear. I thought the same; just wanted to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Note that code compiled with ARC _will_ initialize to `nil` all strong pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: I don't beleive there is any simple way to do this in the way you suggest.

Long answer: You can catch it at runtime...

If you are using ARC all your variables of type Objective-C object reference will be initialised to `nil` by the runtime. However as Eric Skroch suggests a bad access is likely something other than a `nil`.

As a *debugging* aid there are various environment variables which can be set to have the Objective-C runtime print out lots of information as your code runs, see Apple's [Mac OS X Debugging Magic](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2124/_index.html) (that document references an iOS version but its appears to be MIA). However there doesn't seem to be anything for trapping messages to `nil`.

If all else fails use a breakpoint... Here is the start of `objc_msgsend` (OS X):

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x7fff9774d240:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x7fff9774d243:  je     0x7fff9774d270            ; objc_msgSend + 48
0x7fff9774d245:  testb  $0x1, %dil
0x7fff9774d249:  jne    0x7fff9774d287            ; objc_msgSend + 71
0x7fff9774d24c:  movq   (%rdi), %r11
0x7fff9774d24f:  pushq  %rax
0x7fff9774d250:  movq   0x10(%r11), %r10
0x7fff9774d254:  movl   %esi, %eax
0x7fff9774d256:  andl   (%r10), %eax
0x7fff9774d259:  movq   0x10(%r10,%rax,8), %r11
0x7fff9774d25e:  incl   %eax
0x7fff9774d260:  testq  %r11, %r11
0x7fff9774d263:  je     0x7fff9774d29b            ; objc_msgSend + 91
0x7fff9774d265:  cmpq   (%r11), %rsi
0x7fff9774d268:  jne    0x7fff9774d256            ; objc_msgSend + 22
0x7fff9774d26a:  popq   %rax
0x7fff9774d26b:  jmpq   *0x10(%r11)
0x7fff9774d26f:  nop    
0x7fff9774d270:  movq   -0x19eb41e7(%rip), %rdi   ; _objc_nilReceiver
0x7fff9774d277:  testq  %rdi, %rdi
0x7fff9774d27a:  jne    0x7fff9774d245            ; objc_msgSend + 5
0x7fff9774d27c:  xorl   %eax, %eax
```

The last instruction is the first one hit when its determined the receiver is definitely `nil`. So if you think you might have an accidental message to `nil` you can breakpoint on that instruction - the LLDB docs will tell you how if you don't know.

HTH.